# Side Menu Bar background color turned black

Tags: codenameone

I was trying to use the color picker in the theme.css to match the background of my side menu to a background image. After I chose the fourth color the side menu background color turned black. I removed the style from the theme.css, and no change. I deleted the set.uiid assignment for the side menu, and no change. I changed the set.uiid of the side menu to another style, and no change. Does anyone know how to release the black background color, or will deleting the css and start again clear it?

Answer (score 0):

Live CSS updates have limits. I suggest restarting the simulator. If that doesn't work delete the `res` file from your project hierarchy and rerun the project.

Comment: Thanks, Shai. I will work with the CSS and try to clean it up.